# Vue.js cannot show page well

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I could see a proper page after refreshing (F5)
I think that there is a problem to render markers

- I get a position data to draw markers in map api from Json-server
- To get a data, I'm using axios and Async Await function beforeFountain()
- When I enter a page, I could not see markers
- After refreshing this page (push F5), I could see markers
- What I tried to resolve this problem

  - changed axios get functions, code sequence

Position data:

```
{
   "manholes":[
      {
         "id":0,
         "lat":37.55009275087953,
         "lng":127.05067540273716,
         "type":"point"
      },
      {
         "id":1,
         "lat":37.5501997640179,
         "lng":127.04793121391802,
         "type":"point"
      }
   ]
}
```

Vue.js script:

```
data: () => ({
      manholes: [],
    }),
    beforeMount () {
      this.getManholeData()
    },
    mounted () {
      window.kakao && window.kakao.maps
        ? this.initMap()
        : this.addKakaoMapScript()
    },
    methods: {
      // axios get function with async await
      async getManholeData () {
        try {
          const baseURI = 'http://localhost:3000/manholes'
          const response = await this.$axios.get(baseURI)
          this.manholes = response.data
        } catch (ex) {
          console.log(ex)
        }
      },
      initMap () {
         // Map API config
        var container = document.getElementById('map') 
        var options = {
          center: new kakao.maps.LatLng(37.5500792286216, 127.0506923683668), 
          level: 3,
        }
        var map = new kakao.maps.Map(container, options) 

        var imageSrc = require('@/assets/manhole.png') 
        var imageSize = new kakao.maps.Size(32, 32) 
        var imageOption = { offset: new kakao.maps.Point(30, 30) } 

        var markerImage = new kakao.maps.MarkerImage(imageSrc, imageSize, imageOption)

        this.manholes.forEach(function (data) {
          //use position data
          console.log(data.lat)
          console.log(data.lng)
          var marker = new kakao.maps.Marker({
            position: new kakao.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng),
            image: markerImage,
            map: map,
            clickable: true,
          })

          var iwContent = document.createElement('div')
          iwContent.className = 'infowindow'
          // iwContent.setAttribute('style', 'width:165px;text-align:center;padding:5px')
      }
```

My problem:

[image]

My Goal:

[image]

Comment: Can you show `addKakaoMapScript`? and link to a repro (codepen/codesandbox)?

Comment: @tony19 https://codepen.io/chikichaka/pen/QWEzjeM   here it is. I think problem is that mounted() excution before axios response. I added some debugg picture.

Comment: I meant a reproduction of the problem. The codepen you linked only provides `addKakaoMapScript`.